# Does the latest enum value will always be higher than the first enum value?

Tags: objective-c, c, enums, enumeration

I have a question about enum : when I create an enum, does the latest value will always be higher than the first value of the enum ?

Maybe an exemple will be helpful to understand what I mean :

- Imagine I am developing a RPG game, in which there are weapons. Each weapon has a type :

  ```
  typedef enum
  {
    WoodenSword,
    IronSword,
    SteelSword,
    GoldenSword
  }WeaponType;
  ```

Now I want to check the difference of power between the weapons (supposing the WoodenSword is the weakest weapon and the GoldenSword is the strongest weapon). Is it possible de check the power of a weapon doing a simple :

```
    WeaponType type = GoldenSword;
    if(type > WoodenSword)
    {
      //Do something
    }
```

In other words, I don't want this but is it possible for an enum value to be like this (if you don't force the value) :

```
    typedef enum
    {
      WoodenSword, //-> equals 40
      IronSword, //-> equals 0
      SteelSword, //-> equals 42
      GoldenSword //-> equals 5
    }WeaponType;
```

Or it will be this way by default :

```
    typedef enum
    {
      WoodenSword, //-> equals 0
      IronSword, //-> equals 1
      SteelSword, //-> equals 2
      GoldenSword //-> equals 3
    }WeaponType;
```

Hope to be clear enough. Please, feel free to tell me if I am not precise enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For C:

From the C99 standard section *6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers*:

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.98) An enumerator with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. **Each subsequent enumerator with no = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.** (The use of enumerators with = may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.) The enumerators of an enumeration are also known as its members.

So, if the value of an `enum` enumerator is not explicitly set it is guaranteed to be one greater than the previous value.

Comment: And are we sure that ObjC is required to follow the C standard? :-)

Comment: Okay, I'll give you +1 now, since you've quoted the standard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) (objective-C rely on C standard, so I guess the standard is also true for Objective-C)

Comment: All Objective-C files are compile with the argument -std=N, -std=c99 with clang version 4.1, or gcc 4.2. So yes we are sure that ObjC follow C standard. (-std=c89 was used for Objective-C 1, if I remember weel)

Answer (score 3):

C/C++ guarantees that if you don't force values, any next non-forced value in enum will be previous + 1.

Comment: And C++ has _what, exactly_ to do with this question?

Comment: @paxdiablo Other users who have the exact same question about C++ may stumble upon this page through a Google search, as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the default behavior is how you describe. To get the other behavior, you need to set values like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    WoodenSword = 40, //-> equals 40
    IronSword   = 0,  //-> equals 0
    SteelSword  = 42, //-> equals 42
    GoldenSword = 5   //-> equals 5
} WeaponType;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't force subsequent values you can rely on it, unless ...

```
root@debian:/home/david# cat demo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

enum {a = INT_MAX, b};

int main(void)
{
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}

root@debian:/home/david# clang -o demo demo.c
demo.c:4:20: warning: overflow in enumeration value
enum {a = INT_MAX, b};
                   ^
1 warning generated.
root@debian:/home/david# ./demo
a=2147483647 b=-2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use defines instead of enumaration

```
#define IronSword      0
#define GoldenSword    5
#define WoodenSword   40
#define SteelSword    42
```

and

```
if(type > WoodenSword)
{
   //Do something
}
```